# How to pick up the 4th card after a tie?

Tags: c#

I have this card war game; the game starts with each player flipping over 1 card and whomever has the highest card wins. If there is a tie, the next three cards in the deck are played face down and the 4th card dealt face up, whomever has the highest card wins. The game is played until 1 player has all of the cards; however, I haven’t been able to finish it correctly, it crashes every time that I hit enter after the statement "lets flipping cards," and I haven’t been able to make the players to get the 4th card because when using a third variable `r3`, it crashes likewise.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PTCB12WARGAME2
{

    class Card
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Value;
        public string Suit;
        public override string ToString() { return string.Format("{0} of {1}", Name, Suit); }
    }
    class DeckOfCards
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Card> DeckOfCards = new List<Card>();
            var names = new[] { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
                     "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

            var suits = new[] { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades" };

            var cards = new List<Card>();

            // Populate our deck of cards with two nested loops
            foreach (var suit in suits)
            {
                // We use a 'for' loop here instead of 'foreach' so we can use the index to 
                // populate the Value (which is always one more than the index of the name)
                for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                {
                    cards.Add(new Card { Name = names[i], Value = i + 1, Suit = suit });
                }
            }
            //Display deck of 52 cards

            Console.WriteLine("Each player is flipping over 1 card and whomever has the highest card wins");
            Console.ReadLine();



            for (int i = 0; i < DeckOfCards.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DeckOfCards[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            // create just ONCE the random object
            Random random = new Random();

            List<Card> deckOfPlayer1 = new List<Card>();
            List<Card> deckOfPlayer2 = new List<Card>();

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Let's flip cards");
                string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userAnswer == "quit")
                    break;
                // pick a random card for player 1
                int r1;
                r1 = random.Next(0, DeckOfCards.Count);
                Card c1 = DeckOfCards[r1];
                deckOfPlayer1.Add(c1);
              

                // pick a random card for player 2
                int r2;
                r2 = random.Next(0, DeckOfCards.Count);
                Card c2 = DeckOfCards[r2];
                deckOfPlayer2.Add(c2);
               

                Console.WriteLine("Player1 has: {0}", c1);
                Console.WriteLine("Player2 has: {0}", c2);


                // now compare the cards

                if (c1.Value == c2.Value )
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Its a tie! Next three cards in deck are played face down, " +
                        "4th card face up, whoever has the highest card wins");

                     int r3;
                    r3 = random.Next(0, DeckOfCards.Count);
                    Card c3 = DeckOfCards[3];
                    deckOfPlayer1.Add(c3);


                    Console.WriteLine(deckOfPlayer1[3]);
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(deckOfPlayer2[3]);

                   

                    if (c1.Value > c2.Value && c2.Value != 1)
                     {
                        deckOfPlayer1.Add(c2);
                        deckOfPlayer2.Remove(c2);
                        Console.WriteLine("Player1 wins");
                     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Player2 wins");
                        deckOfPlayer2.Add(c1);
                        deckOfPlayer1.Remove(c1);
                    }

                }

                else if (c1.Value == 1 || (c1.Value > c2.Value && c2.Value != 1))
                {
                    deckOfPlayer1.Add(c2);
                    deckOfPlayer2.Remove(c2);
                    Console.WriteLine("Player1 wins");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player2 wins");
                    deckOfPlayer2.Add(c1);
                    deckOfPlayer1.Remove(c1);
                }


            } while (deckOfPlayer1.Count < 52 || (deckOfPlayer2.Count < 52));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "It crashes" is not a problem statement we can assist with. Be specific.

Comment: In addition to @IanKemp You might want to correct your code or at least explain the process. Is it normal that player can both take out ace of spade every single draw ?

Comment: You create, but never seem to populate `DeckOfCards`.

Comment: It crashes by making a circle with a red cross in front of Card c1 = DeckOfCards[r1]; 
 and stating "Exception unhandled, SystemArgmentOutOfRangeException :Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection".

Comment: You seem to be declaring two variables that do the same thing: `DeckOfCards` and `cards`. Remove `cards` and use `DeckOfCards` in the nested `for-loop`.

Comment: There are 52 cards in a deck. 2-10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace (Ace is the highest card)
It is a 2 player game, each player starts with 26 cards (half the deck)
The game starts with each player flipping over 1 card and whomever has the highest card wins.
If there is a tie, the next three cards in your deck are played face down and the 4th card dealt face up, whoemever has the highest card wins.
The game is played until 1 player has all of the cards.

Comment: No, Mr. Franck, is not normal that player can both take out ace of spade every single draw.

Comment: zmike and 500 are onto it. You've got two lists of cards and are using the wrong list.

Comment: I removed the variable cards. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, please learn how to use interactive debugging. If all you know is "it crashed", then you're going to struggle to find and eliminate bugs in your code. [Here's one tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019) you can start with.

In this instance, the problem is likely due to your use of two lists:

```
List<Card> DeckOfCards = new List<Card>();         // One here
var names = new[] { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
         "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

var suits = new[] { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades" };

var cards = new List<Card>();                      // And one here
```

You are populating the second one with `cards.Add`, but you are trying to access the first one everywhere else, for example with these lines:

```
r1 = random.Next(0, DeckOfCards.Count);
Card c1 = DeckOfCards[r1];
```

Remove one of the lists, replace it with the other instance, and your code will have a better chance of running (disclaimer: I haven't compiled it to check for other issues)